# Default controller route parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get the param from the following URL: https://www.mysite.com/param

Below rout works to get the param, but the rest of the routs, such as mysite.com/rout1 stop working for an obvious reason.

What would the rout look like handle this?

Controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string userId)
        {
            if (userId != null)
            {
                //do stuff
            }


            return View();
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "UserId",
        url: "{userId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );          

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I'm also using a custom controller factory:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "UserId",
        url: "{userId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

to

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "UserId",
        url: "{userId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", userId = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this as weel, but the issues is that other routs, such as mysite.com/rout1 stop working. The routing engine cannot tell the difference between a param and a route name.

Comment: is that all the routings you have? my other guess is that there is another route above it which is taking over the incoming request.

Comment: try: public ActionResult Index(string userId = "0")

Answer (score 0):

These routes should fix your problem -

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserId",
            url: "{UserId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", UserId = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { UserId = @"[A-Za-z0-9]+" } 
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When you try following

- `/123` or `/abc` or `/abc123` -> it will take you to **Customer** Controller **Details** Action
- `/` or `/Home/Index/123` or `/Home/Index/abc` or `/Home/Index/123abc` or `/Home/Index` or `/Home/Index?id=123` or `/Home/Index?id=abc` or `/Home/Index?id=123abc` -> it will take you to **Home** controller **Index** action

Comment: This still breaks other index routs like: /MyRoute, but you gave me a right idea to use the "constraints". My user Ids are Guid's, so I tweaked the regex to look for them. Thx. I'll keep the question open for few more days. Thx.

Comment: @VoidRay, can I know more information about other routes which are being broken?

Comment: Sure, for example: mysite.com/Account